# Как лучше написать Стратегию?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть абстрактный класс(интерфейс) Presentation, у которого два потомка SpritePresentation и ShapePresentation, как лучше написать чисто виртуальный метод, если это возможно, который будет задавать изображения для каждого представления, ведь параметры будут разные. Не хотелось бы писать перегрузки, т.к. у объектов этих классов будут доступны лишние методы.

Comment: А вы опишите какие параметры будут у одного, а какие у другого. Также не совсем понятно причём тут Стратегия, я вижу у вас только проблему с наследованием и прототипом интерфейса

Comment: Ну это же композиция, которая реализуется в классах-сущностях, для увеличения гибкости кода. А параметры: для одного представления, например: (int x, int y, int width, int height), для второго: (string path)

Comment: @Abyx, чтобы быть в абстрактном интерфейсе :-)

Comment: Возможно, стоит инкапсулировать параметры в объект или структуру?

Comment: Стратегия - это паттерн, проявляющийся всегда и во всём. Фундаментальный паттерн ООП. Конкретизируйте - что надо, добавьте исходников.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае существует несколько способов передачи нужных данных разным стратегиям, которые могут потребовать разных входных данных.

Во-первых, сами аргументы могут быть полиморфными:

```
class DrawingContext abstract {
public:
    virtual ~DrawingContext() {}
};

class SpriteDrawingContext : public DrawingContext {
};

class ShapeDrawingContext : public DrawingContext {
};

class Presentation abstract
{
public:
    virtual ~Presentation() {};
    virtual void Draw(const DrawingContext& context) abstract;
};

class SpritePresentation : public Presentation {
public:
    virtual void Draw(const DrawingContext& context) override {
        // Упадем, если context будет другого типа.
        // Можно кастить к указателю и бросать исключение/ассертить
        auto spriteContext = dynamic_cast<const SpriteDrawingContext&>(context); 
        // обрабатываем spritecontext
    }
};

class ShapePresentation : public Presentation {
public:
    virtual void Draw(const DrawingContext& context) override {
        // Упадем, если context будет другого типа.
        // Можно кастить к указателю и бросать исключение/ассертить
        auto shapeDrawingContext = dynamic_cast<const ShapeDrawingContext&>(context);
        // обрабатываем shapeDrawingContext
    }
};
```

В этом случае, аргументы метода являются полиморфными и каждая стратегия может задаункастить их к нужному и выполнить нужную работу.

Однако в этом случае мы легко можем получить ошибку во время исполнения, поскольку через интерфейс базового класса совершенно не ясно, какие аргументы являются допустимыми, а какие - нет.

Альтернатива такая: передать нужный контекст при конструировании конкретной стратегии и дать ей возможность получить нужные данные, которые нужны для выполнения определенной операции.

```
class SpriteDrawingContext {
};

class ShapeDrawingContext {
};

class Presentation abstract
{
public:
    virtual ~Presentation() {};
    virtual void Draw() abstract;
};

class SpritePresentation : public Presentation {
    const SpriteDrawingContext& context_;
public:
    SpritePresentation(const SpriteDrawingContext& context): context_(context) {}

    virtual void Draw() override {
        // используем SpriteDrawingContext
    }
};

class ShapePresentation : public Presentation {
    const ShapeDrawingContext& context_;
public:
    ShapePresentation(const ShapeDrawingContext& context) : context_(context) {}

    virtual void Draw() override {
        // используем ShapeDrawingContext
    }
};
```

В этом случае контексты никак не связаны между собой, а метод `draw` перестал принимать какие-либо аргументы. Для реализации конкретной операции, каждая стратегия обратиться к экземпляру конкретного контекста для получения из нее нужных данных.

Первый случай реализован с использованием 'push-модели' взаимодействия, когда все нужные данные принудительно передаются в операции. Второй вариант - это такая-себе 'pull-модель' взимодействия, когда каждый тип стратегии получает свой собственный контекст и "вытягивает" нужные ей данные для выполнения той или иной операции.

Comment: Очень понравился второй вариант. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Да, он наиболее вменяемый.